# Реализация контроллера в шаблоне MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Могу ли я реализовать в своём контроллере событие? Где я должен буду подписать другой/другие контролеры на это событие? Противоречит ли это самому шаблону?

Comment: Начнем с того что в чистом виде сей шаблон не используется практически нигде, допустим в Java Swing написан на MVC, но это не мешало им связать вид и контроллеры и полностью абстрагироватся только от модели. Важно понимать что вы пишете и действительно ли вам это нужно, если да - реализовывайте, шаблоны это всеголишь методика и вариант написания(идея если хотите) и вы не обязаны следовать ее на все 100%.

Comment: просто на всех схемах описания паттерна MVC описывается только связи/отношения между моделью, представлением и контроллером, но нет ни одного описания связей/отношений между разными контроллерами.

Comment: И это тоже истино, вообще контроллер в MVC саммая туманная составляющая...

Comment: кстати, всем советую не писать свои реализации микроархитектур уровня приложения, это довольно сложный и объемный труд (хотя на первый взгляд так не кажется) используйте готовые, проверенные временем и людьми решения, например PureMVC - http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_CSharp/

Comment: мой вопрос касался исключительно ASP.net MVC Framework

Comment: надо же, неожиданно, и там нет схемы для сигналов/событий, весьма странно

Comment: единственный мне известный способ взаимодействия контролееров между собой - это методы ``RedirectToRoute`` и ``RedirectToAction``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все контроллеры внутри приложения унаследовать от `ControllerBase` класса, внутри него создать статический `dispatcher`, невидимый в классах наследниках, наружу оставить видимые методы для подписки и отписки слушателей + отправка событий.

пример кода, **[отсюда](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9aackb16.aspx)**, очень советую почитать

код не проверялся, используйте как набросок

```
class ControllerBase
{
    public delegate void AlarmEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public static event AlarmEventHandler Alarm;

    public void addEventListener(EventListenerClass c)
    {
        AlarmEventHandler aeh = new AlarmEventHandler(c.eventListenerMethod);
        saveAlarmEventHandler(aeh);  // Save 
        Alarm += aeh;
    }

    public void removeEventListener(EventListenerClass c)
    {
        AlarmEventHandler aeh = getAlarmEventHandler(c.eventListenerMethod);  // Get
        Alarm -= aeh;
    }

    public void OnEvent(AlarmEventArgs e)
    {
        AlarmEventHandler handler = Alarm;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // Invokes the delegates.
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

помните, если контроллер динамический, то он должен сам "чистить" слушатели при удалении

и еще, то что все контроллеры "видят" глобальные события, есть очень не гуд, можно долго рассказывать, но это существенный подводный камень, как вариант делают некий глобальный контекст который сам диспетчеризует все события и дает их видеть только нужным контроллерам

Comment: Привести пример кода можете?

Comment: Позже, студию поставлю.

Comment: спасибо за код - сподвигло на несколько интересных идей, напрмер сделать обработчком некоторого события ``ActionResult`` того или иного котроллера, такое возможно? ``ActionResult`` корректно отработает?

Comment: **Encapsulates the result of an action method and is used to perform a framework-level operation on behalf of the action method.**
это простой враппер, какая то слишком абстрактная идея, лучше это без меня, напишите отдельный пост

Comment: В примере объявлено статическое событие. Подписывает на это событие и вызывают его - методы экземпляра (нестатические). Чем не подходит обычное статическое событие?

Comment: более подходящего решения я не нашёл, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: 2Tolyandre - привычка понижать связанность классов, + глобальные статические поля = кошмарный сон для любой архитектуры, этого все избегают, + сам класс должен содержать функционал, не распыляя его по другим типам